# adding a dynamic drawable background to textView

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable, xml-drawable, shapedrawable

I want to add dynamic background using drawable to a textView.
I want the resulting textView to have the anything similar with the following background.

This exact image doesn't matter. I just want to learn how to code this.

Is there any way of achieving this without using a bitmap directly for background.

[image: background]

Comment: You need is Draw 9-patch - http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: @Alexander are there any other options

Comment: No. For vector simple graphics use xml or canvas overriding.